# Should we initialize Docker daemon every time when we restart the blockchain server?

Tags: docker, blockchain

From the document in the  following link: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/dev-setup/install.md

we've got to know that we should do

```
Make sure that the Docker daemon initialization includes the options

-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

However, should we initialize the docker every time we restart the blockchain server?
In addition, I conduct the following command:

```
nohup docker daemon -g /data/docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock&
```

What does `-g /data/docker` mean?

Answer (score 0):

The options you are passing to docker do the following:

- `-g /data/docker`: this changes the runtime directory from /var/lib/docker to the one you've provided
- `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375`: this tells docker to listen on all network interfaces to port 2375, unencrypted. **Caution: this allows anyone with network access to your machine to have full root access, a firewall or isolated machine is required for security.**
- `-H unit:///var/run/docker.sock`: this tells docker to process commands from any user with access to this socket, typically restricted to root and members of the "docker" group.

I'm not familiar with the blockchain install, but typically a docker engine can restart the containers contained within, so it should not be required to restart, only start it on boot as a service.